# Thrust force on wind turbine

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

Could someone explain me how thrust force produces a bending moment on top of the wind power plant's tower?

Comment: it's not any more complicated than wind against a tree tends to blow it over.

Comment: the main cause that the tower bends is due to bending moments coming from the rotor or due to wind hitting the whole structure.Please explain

Comment: it's the wind against the rotor.

Comment: Do you understand the shear forces and moments on a cantilever beam? The tower is just a vertical beam.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments I am inferring that your question is about what is causing most of the bending moment.

First of all an example. A 3MW wind generator has the following characteristics :

- hub height $h_h$: 70 m (between 60 and 84 m)
- rotor radius $r\approx 40 m$

Assuming a wind speed of $v=10$ [m/s], the nominal pressure of the wind on the tower is about:

$$q_n = \frac{1}{2}\rho A v^2$$

However, because the rotor in wind generators is rotating usually with a tip-speed ratio $\lambda$ with a value between 6 and 7 then the tip speed ($v_t$) at the ratio is approximately 6 to 7 times greater that the wind speed.

That means that the nominal pressure at the wing tip $q_{n,t} $ will be:

$$q_{n,t} = \frac{1}{2}\rho A v_t^2 =  \frac{1}{2}\rho A (\lambda v)^2$$
$$q_{n,t} = \lambda^2 \frac{1}{2}\rho A (v)^2 =  \lambda^2 q_{n} $$

So the nominal pressure at the wing tip $q_{n,t} $, will be approximately 35 to 50 times more. And although the pressure of the rotor will change with the distance from the hub center, most of the time the nominal pressure is significantly higher.

Therefore the rotors contribute a lot more to the bending moment of the structure compared to the tower.

Comment: Yes correct I want to know what cause more bending to the structure, especially on the tower.Let me recap to see if I get your point. You say that as the wind hits the blades the pressure at the wind tip is very large and this create a bending moment M which varying (let's say linearly) from blade tip to blade base. This bending moment M will be transferred from blade's base to the top of the tower ( like a beam with one end fixed and a bending moment on free edge). This moment is more sugnificant in tower's bending than the wind which hit the tower. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Apart from a few minor points correct. The difference is that pressure will not vary linearly  across the blade (its a more complex relationship), because $\lambda$ changes and also the $C_D, C_L$ at different segments. Additionally the bending moment of the blades is not all in the same direction, and some components counteract each other. The reason why its more significant, is the increased distance from the wind turbine foundation.

Comment: You right I simplified it a lot. But in the end when it comes to severe bending conditions you can simulate the wind tower as a beam fixed one end and a bending moment on the other( keep it as simple as possible).

Comment: The structural concern of the tower is the wind on the exposed surfaces. The wind on the blade is rather complicated due to disturbances of the flow, geometry, and structural properties of the blade. As wind tower is gaining popularity, you shouldn't have much difficulty finding the applicable wind pressure from the design code, and/or the literature in kind.